# MediaPlayer won't play twice unless complete app restart

Tags: android, audio, media-player, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I'm working on a app where I use MediaPlayer to play sounds. The user presses a button and a couple of seconds later a sound starts playing. I call:

```
mp.release();
mp = null;
finish();
```

within onStop() so the MediaPlayer object should be completely destroyed. The first time I use the app everything works just fine but when I exit the screen and return to the one I was in previously (still in my app) and then restart the activity where I play the sound no sound comes up. If I exit the app and remove it from multitasking and the restart it everything works fine.

I play the sound after a postDelayed but that shouldn't change anything since the MediaPlayer object is removed within onStop().

EDIT:

How I start the MediaPlayer object:

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.explosion);
mp.start();
```

Comment: could you update the post with how exactly are you playing the sound and where are you doing that ? are you initializing the object again after you set it to null ?

Comment: @JiMMaR I set it to null, finish the activity, restart the activity and the initilize it again. I'll update the first post with som sample code right away.

Comment: umm... could you share the whole activity ?

Comment: Is there anything in the logcat when trying to play the sound the second time?

Comment: @JiMMaR Here's the code: http://pastebin.com/aQCzhSzC note that I called mp_final mp in my sample code in order to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @JiMMaR opps use this pastebin instead: http://pastebin.com/SzeRvGcp

Comment: @Tim no, logcat doesn't say a thing

Comment: I don't see where you are calling your "start()" method .. you may want to call that in your onResume() method

Comment: why release the MP ? your app is only in background and should not use CPU power but it should hold on to its objects unless they are just temporary

Comment: @JiMMaR start() is called at the end of playFinal(), right at the bottom of all the code

Comment: @NikkyD The objects are temporary. The idea is that the user will exit the app as soon as he/she has listned to the sound

Comment: you call mp_final.start() at the end of playFinal() , but you never call start() [public void start(final View v)] in your code .. I think this should be called inside onResume()

Comment: @JiMMaR What do you mean by "you never call start() [public void start(final View v)] in your code"? It's very unclear. Anyway as the question states the sound starts playing the first time I run the activity.

Comment: it appears to me that you are calling start() method from another activity, as that there is no calling for this method in the code you provided